# Big-O Question: Give a big-O estimate for each of these functions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Further instructions: For the function $g$ in your estimate $f(x) \approx O(g(x))$, use a simple function $g$ of smallest order.

1. $((n^3) + (n^2)  \log(n)) (\log(n) + 1) + (17  \log(n) + 19)  ((n^3) + 2)$
2. $((2^n) + (n^2)) ((n^3) + (3^n))$
3. $((n^n) + n  (2^n) + (5^n)) (n! + (5^n))$

I understand that you take the max one and multiply that, but for question $2$ I don't think $O((2^n)*(3^n))$ is right. It doesn't feel right, so I need an explanation.

Comment: $O(6^n)$ sounds correct.